# How to make UIViewController's view inherit from another UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have one `UIViewController` without NIB file. Now i have one my customized `UIView`. I want to make  `UIViewController`'s view inherit from my customized `UIView`, is it possible ? I know that if I have XIB file than I can make Custom Class from there but without XIB can it be done? [image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `UIViewController` subclass, and don't want to use a nib file, then override the `loadView` method in your subclass:

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[MyView alloc] init];
    // additional view setup here
}
```

If you are just using a generic `UIViewController` (not a subclass), then you might be able to just assign to the view controller's `view` property, like this:

```
vc.view = [[MyView alloc] init];
```

But I'm not sure if that works properly outside of `loadView`.  I haven't seen any documentation that says it is or is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your view controller's view like this:

```
// ViewController.m, in viewDidLoad
self.view = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

A more conventional alternative is to fill the default view with the custom subview, like this:

```
MyCustomView *myCustomView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:myCustomView];
```

Comment: It's more appropriate to set `self.view` in `loadView` instead of `viewDidLoad`.  If you wait until `viewDidLoad`, the default `loadView` will create a `UIView` that is then destroyed by your reassignment.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this in your `.h` file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

with

```
@interface ViewController : Customized View Controller
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to replace the view, not the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to load a custom view programmatically, for that you need to override the `loadView` method of your view controller.

```
-(void)loadView
 {
    [super loadView];
    CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bouds];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
 }
```